# Post Data to Website Form Curl

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to print the data of this page in a array in php, but post the right fields.

Basically i need to submit the data for 2010/2011 and Division Two (Men), I dont know where im going wrong?

```
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.englandbasketball.co.uk/leaguetables/default.aspx");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

      $data = array(
     'ddlStartYear' => '2011',
     'ddlCompetitionGroups' => '540'
 );

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      print ($info);
```

Thanks

Comment: i think you have to print `$output`

Comment: That will just print the hole page, I need to print and see the array to pull out information, thanks anyway tho.

Comment: You will not get much data from array i guess you want to get the data from the table with results after pressing the "Refresh league table". Like jogesh_p wrote you need to print the $output. If you just need to print the array then use print_r($info); instead.
You did the right thing with the CURL so it should work - no mistakes there but form "use" javascript or something so it's usually not very easy to post the data with CURL. Also check the source code if there is any other (hidden) field which should also be posted in order to post the data.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, will look into this I will try Soap like rahul said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to submit form with your information (2010/2011) and want to get result 
 in array. If i am right them you should use SOAP. and there should be a function to handle your data to proceed them.

[Please read this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)